# Prevent lxml selecting next text node after matched element

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I need to find `<div>` with `id="XXX"` in some HTML string template:

```
from lxml import html

template = '''
Text node 1
<div id="XXX">XXX content</div>
Text node 2
'''

tree = html.fromstring(template)
element = tree.get_element_by_id('XXX')
result = html.tostring(element).decode('utf-8')

print(result)

>>> <div id="XXX">XXX content</div>
>>> Text node 2
```

**It selects `<div>` and next `Text node 1` for some strange reasons**

---

If I wrap `<div id="XXX">XXX content</div>` with another `<div>` to:

```
Text node 1
<div>
    <div id="XXX">XXX content</div>
</div>
Text node 2
```

Everything is better, it prints matched `<div id="XXX">` and a blank line (decoded `\n`):

```
>>> print(result)
<div id="XXX">XXX content</div>
\n
```

---

If I add some `<div>` after `<div id="XXX">` to:

```
Text node 1
<div id="XXX">XXX content</div>
<div></div>
Text node 2
```

Everything is also better, it prints matched `<div id="XXX">` and a blank line (decoded `\n`):

```
>>> print(result)
<div id="XXX">XXX content</div>
\n
```

---

*Previous `Text node 1` never affected - at least this is fine)*

So, can something be specified not to select next text nodes?
It'll be awesome, if `\n` also will not match, but I could live with that

Please, tell me, if that problem related not to `lxml`, but to XPath in general

P.S. `BeautifulSoup` doesn't have this problems, even using same `lxml` module as parser, it even does not match next `\n`

**VERSIONS:**

```
>>> python
Python 3.7.3

>>> pip show lxml
Version: 4.3.4
```

Comment: I can't replicate the problem; my output for your code exactly is `<div id="XXX">XXX content</div>`.
`

Comment: @JackFleeting, Hi, could you tell please your exact `python` and `lxml` versions?

Comment: @MaxCore :  use result.strip()

Comment: Sure: python - 3.6.8 (running in a Jupyter notebook under Win 7); lxml - 4.3.3.

Comment: @JackFleeting I am an idiot, I put wrong and working example in first block that demonstrates a problem, Sorry*1000. Now fixed, now it should not work) It is working as I've described even here: https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_python_debugger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like sometimes one just has to use brute force:

```
tree = html.fromstring(template)
element = tree.get_element_by_id('XXX')

element.tail = None #brute force in action....

result = html.tostring(element).decode('utf-8')
print(result)
```

Outputs the desired

```
<div id="XXX">XXX content</div>
```

Now it's up to people smarter than me to explain why we need to resort to this...

Comment: It works!) "tail" - missed keyword) This also do the job: html.tostring(element, with_tail=False)